# Strict URLBinding for Stripes

Tags: stripes

How can I achieve *strict* UrlBinding in Stripes? *Strict* means for me that there should be no default handler for undefined events except the empty event.

```
/hello -> DefaultHandler -> currentDate()
/hello/currentDate -> currentDate()
/hello/randomDate -> randomDate()
/hello/* -> DefaultHandler (I want a 404)
```

The problem also exists for only one event because it is automatically a default handler.
Following code is taken from the [Stripes](https://pragprog.com/book/fdstr/stripes) book.

```
@UrlBinding("/hello/{$event}")
public class HelloActionBean implements ActionBean {

    private static final String VIEW = "/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp";
    private ActionBeanContext ctx;

    public ActionBeanContext getContext() {
        return ctx;
    }

    public void setContext(ActionBeanContext ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    private Date date;
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    @DefaultHandler
    public Resolution currentDate() {
        date = new Date();
        return new ForwardResolution(VIEW);
    }

    public Resolution randomDate() {
        long max = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long random = new Random().nextLong() % max;
        date = new Date(random);
        return new ForwardResolution(VIEW);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this can be done in a more generic 'Stripes' way (perhaps writing your own `ActionResolver`) but here's a workaround 
that adds a method `defHandler` set as `@DefaultHandler` (instead of `currentDate`). This added method forwards to `currentDate` when no value for `$event` is given, otherwise returns a 404 `ErrorResolution`.

Requests for the `currentDate` and `randomDate` events do not pass through `defHandler` because they have their own handler method.

```
@DefaultHandler
public Resolution defHandler () {

    // The request uri
    Path path = Paths.get( getContext().getRequest().getRequestURI() );

    // Get the action name from the @UrlBinding value
    Path action = Paths.get( this.getClass().getAnnotation( UrlBinding.class ).value().split("/\\{")[0] );

    // no event specified -> currentDate
    if ( path.getFileName().equals( action.getFileName() ) ) return currentDate();

    // unknown event specified -> 404
    else return new ErrorResolution(404);
}
```